# Highcharts Pie chart display legend always as floating

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I work with hightcharts for a while and it is amazing library. But I am stuck with legend in Pie chart. Legend is always displaying like floating, but i need legend under pie.

I got this :-/

[image: Legend is floating]

I want this :D

[image: Legend on bottom]

My definition is:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "margin": 0,
    "type": "pie",
    "height": 300,
    "backgroundColor": "#FDFDFD",
    "width": 250
  },
  "legend": {
    "floating": false,
    "align": "center",
    "verticalAlign": "bottom",

  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "pie": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false,
      },
      "size": "100%",
      "showInLegend": true,

    }
  },
  "title": false,
  "exporting": false,
  "series": [{
    "data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  }],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **margin**. Set margin to null, or remove this line and it will be fixed.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "margin": null,
  },...
});
```

Bonus tip: floating of legend is disabled by default, you can remove this line too.